# AWS Glue disable sslmode for target connections

Tags: mysql, jdbc, etl, aws-glue

Am quite new to AWS Glue; we are building an ETL process that pulls data from an external source on a MySQL database into Redshift.

After adding the `connections` it and testing them it would connect successfully to the instance (without sslmode).

[image: log from connection tests]

*CloudWatch: Logs for testing connection*

```
Container: container_1534777629478_0001_01_000001 on ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal_8041
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Mon Aug 20 15:12:58 +0000 2018
LogLength:7583
Log Contents:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2018-08-20-15-12-25.py", line 20, in <module>
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "monolith", table_name = "profile_user", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1534777629478_0001/container_1534777629478_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 559, in from_catalog
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1534777629478_0001/container_1534777629478_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 136, in create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1534777629478_0001/container_1534777629478_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_source.py", line 36, in getFrame
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1534777629478_0001/container_1534777629478_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1534777629478_0001/container_1534777629478_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1534777629478_0001/container_1534777629478_0001_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o62.getDynamicFrame.
: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 49 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 46 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:104)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4812)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1629)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCUtils.scala:691)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCUtils.scala:690)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.com$amazonaws$services$glue$util$JDBCWrapper$$catchSSLException(JDBCUtils.scala:657)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectWithSSLAttempt(JDBCUtils.scala:652)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties$lzycompute(JDBCUtils.scala:689)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties(JDBCUtils.scala:673)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.getRawConnection(JDBCUtils.scala:706)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource.getPrimaryKeys(DataSource.scala:604)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.JDBCDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:572)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSource$class.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:70)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkSQLDataSource.getDynamicFrame(DataSource.scala:529)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:89)
... 37 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
... 45 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
```

It seems like the job is failing for unable to allocate SSL PKIX path. We also tried to disable `sslmode=disabled` in the JDBC connection string but seems without effect on the job.

MySQL version 5.3

Any advice/guidance would be highly appreciated,

Thanks